# Jest test takes 75 seconds but each test only a few milliseconds

Tags: reactjs, github, jestjs, cicd

I have a Jest output that looks like this on our CI (github) workflow thing.

```
PASS a/b/c.spec.tsx (75.856 s)
  Test
    ✓ should a (45 ms)
    ✓ should b (53 ms)
    ✓ should c (19 ms)
    ✓ should d (13 ms)
    ✓ should e (12 ms)
    ✓ should f (14 ms)
    ✓ should g (18 ms)
```

On my local setup, it takes 7 seconds. It also doesn't seem to matter how many individual tests I remove, the time is about the same (which makes sense, each test is only a few ms). My tests just look like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Foo from './foo';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('should a', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(
      <Foo
        text="SomeText"
        number={0}
        moretext="More Text"
      />
    );
    expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should b', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(
      <Foo
        text="SomeText"
        number={0}
        moretext="More Text"
      />
    );
    expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    expect(baseElement.querySelector('h2')).toHaveTextContent(
      'SomeText'
    );
  });
```

... etc. Everything is done with query selector. But again, each test is fast. Why on earth does it take 75 seconds (consistently) to run on GitHub CI if each test only a few ms? Even 7 seconds is painful on my local setup.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide your workflow yaml? I have a suspection, that it takes a long time, because it is downloading all your node-modules

Comment: I think you are right. I deleted the test and basically a different test reported "75 seconds", so yeah.

Answer (score 1):

After a significant amount of debugging, I found that the root cause is setupFilesAfterEnv and other setup files, which run again for each individual test file. If you have "expensive" iterations in these files, or if you're using requireActual for large libraries, this could be causing slower performance. It's noteworthy that as the number of tests increases, performance decreases. You may notice that the last tests in the buffer are the slowest, regardless of their complexity, and they are also associated with larger memory heaps.

To alleviate this issue, I placed the mocks for these libraries under a `__mocks__` directory. This significantly reduced test times, as Jest will only execute these mocks when the given paths are actively required during tests.

For instance, consider a library named neck-js. Instead of the following code:

```
jest.mock('neck-js', () => ({
__esModule: true,
default: 'bob',
somethingElse: jest.fn(),
}));
```

You can create a directory named **mocks**/neck-js and include:

```
export default 'bob';
export const somethingElse = jest.fn();
```

Although Jest's lint rules discourage it, you can directly access the exported mocked objects, change their implementation, or check for calls. In my experience, this approach results in a more organized codebase and becomes easier to manage on larger projects.

This is not the only thing you can do to increase speed and decrease RAM usage; a developer has made several great tips [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17171#issuecomment-1643931883) worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Have experienced the same slowness with Jest testing - especially running in Windows environment. It is reportedly very OS-dependent, and takes some time to start up - apparently related to how it analyses your dependencies before it starts the test so they can be run faster later, which explains why removing tests do little to reduce the test duration.

There are multiple issues reported [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7963), [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7619) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6694) etc, so it's a known issue and there's on-going work to optimize some of this performance, but it might be worth considering other test frameworks like Jasmine or Mocha as well.